# Flutter TextField with Tagging people functionality

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

Is there a way to simulate mentioning people/places in TextEditForm, after writing a certain character (let's say **@**)

as an example WhatsApp messaging UI

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Extended text field](https://github.com/fluttercandies/extended_text_field) package by fluttercandies.